# Batch can't import string from file and associate to var

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, batch-file, version

I'm trying associate Google Chrome version to variable in my script in batch, but

```
powershell -Command "& {(Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo.ProductVersion } > chromever.txt
set /p version=<chromever.txt
echo %version%
pause
```

text in file is: 97.0.4692.71
but console output return: ■9 ■9

Please help...

Comment: I bet `chromever.txt` is a Unicode file (open it with Notepad, go to Save As and find out in the file dialog), but Command Prompt expects ASCII/ANSI encoding…

Answer (score 0):

The immediate fix is to use `Set-Content` rather than `>`:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo.ProductVersion | Set-Content chromever.txt"
```

<sup>Note that I've removed `"& { ... }"` around your `-Command` argument, because it is never necessary - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.</sup>

The problem is that `>` in Windows PowerShell (`powershell.exe`) produces "Unicode"-encoded (UTF-16LE-encoded) files by default, which `cmd.exe` doesn't decode properly (by default). `Set-Content` defaults to ANSI encoding (a superset of ASCII), and since you're only retrieving a version number composed of ASCII-range-characters only, no encoding issues should arise.

---

Alternatively, you could use a `for /f` loop to parse PowerShell's output directly, without the need to save to a temporary file:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`
  powershell -c "(Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo.ProductVersion"
`) do set version=%%i

echo [%version%]
```

Comment: You're the best, thanks ;)

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @BatchProblem123. Allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment:

Answer (score 0):

I would say, before you attempt to claim that there is a problem with your output, you should consider posting a properly complete commandline.

This has imbalanced doublequotes:

```sh
powershell -Command "& {(Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo.ProductVersion } > chromever.txt
```

Had you actually included the missing doublequote, and done so in the correct location, you wouldn't have received output from PowerShell in Unicode (UTF-16 LE).

Incorrect Location:

```sh
powershell -Command "& {(Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo.ProductVersion } > chromever.txt"
```

Had you placed it correctly, the output would have been in ANSI:

Correct Location:

```sh
powershell -Command "& {(Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo.ProductVersion }" > chromever.txt
```

Essentially because you've missed that doublequote off, it was effectively closed at the end of the line, (the redirection *`>`* was being done in PowerShell). Hence your result was returned in UTF-16 LE, instead of the required ANSI encoding ,(when the redirection is done in cmd.exe).

---

Personally however, I'd have done it like this:

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -Command "(Get-Item $(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo.ProductVersion" 1>"chromever.txt"
@Set /P "version=" 0<"chromever.txt"
@Echo(%version%
```

And If I didn't actually need the text file:

```sh
@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -Command "(Get-Item $(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo.ProductVersion" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "version=%%G"
@Echo(%version%
```